# Embed flash object loads with border but then border dissapears

Tags: javascript, html, flash, embed

When loading initially there is a border, but then it disappears soon after (almost instantaneously).  I am using the embed tag.

It only appears to be happening for iexplorer9-11 (oddly no problem with ie8 or other browsers).  I  just need to hide the border when it first loads.

Comment: Is it possible to see the code? Or a jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you tried in CSS border:0 for your element? Or in html attributes border="0"?

Comment: I found out it was a slow file loading issue. I masked the problem by making outer div a fixed width and height with overflow:hidden and then using margin-top and margin-left negative in the embed portion which moved the loading border out of sight.

Answer (score 0):

### copy the below code in to your .js file or insert one .js file into your html page

```
theObjects = document.getElementsByTagName("object"); 
for (var i = 0; i < theObjects.length; i++) { 
theObjects[i].outerHTML = theObjects[i].outerHTML; 
}
```

HTML:After putting above code into .js file put below code into your html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Your_file_name.js"></script>
```

---